# Running a task in a separate thread which shold be able to stop on request

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops

I am trying to design an infinite (or a user-defined length) loop that would be independent of my GUI process. I know how to start that loop in a separate thread, so the GUI process is not blocked. However, I would like to have a possibility to interrupt the loop at a press of a button. The complete scenario may look like this:

GUI::startButton->myClass::runLoop... ---> starts a loop in a new thread

GUI::stopButton->myClass::terminateLoop ---> should be able to interrupt the started loop

The problem I have is figuring out how to provide the *stop functionality*. I am sure there is a way to achieve this in C++. I was looking at a number of multithreading related posts and articles, as well as some lectures on how to use async and futures. Most of the examples did not fit my intended use and/or were too complex for my current state of skills.

Example:

GUIClass.cpp

```
MyClass *myClass = new MyClass;

void MyWidget::on_pushButton_start_clicked()
{
    myClass->start().detach();
}

void MyWidget::on_pushButton_stop_clicked()
{
    myClass->stop(); // TBD: how to implement the stop functionality?
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
std::thread MyClass::start()
{
    return std::thread(&MyClass::runLoop, this);
}

void MyClass::runLoop()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)
    {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to stop the thread, you should not be `detach`ing it in the first place.

Comment: Or maybe the OP is asking how to implement a _pause_?

Comment: What I need is the ability to run a complex task in a separate thread, which could potentially be stopped on demand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no standard way to terminate a STL thread. And even if possible, this is not advisable since it can leave your application in an undefined state.

It would be better to add a check to your `MyClass::runLoop` method that stops execution in a controlled way as soon as an external condition is fulfilled. This might, for example, be a control variable like this:

```
std::thread MyClass::start()
{
    _threadRunning = true;
    if(_thread.joinable() == true) // If thr thread is joinable...
    {
        // Join before (re)starting the thread
        _thread.join();
    }
    _thread = std::thread(&MyClass::runLoop, this);
    return _thread;
}
void MyClass::runLoop()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATION_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if(_threadRunning == false) { break; }
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Then you can end the thread with:

```
void MyClass::stopLoop()
{
    _threadRunning = false;
}
```

`_threadRunning` would here be a member variable of type `bool` or, if your architecture for some reason has non-atomic bools, `std::atomic<bool>`.
With x86, x86_64, ARM and ARM64, however, you should be fine without atomic bools. It, however is advised to use them. Also to hint at the fact that the variable is used in a multithreading context.

Possible MyClass.h:

```
MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : _threadRunning(false) {}
    std::thread start();
    std::thread runLoop();
    std::thread stopLoop();
    
private:
    std::thread _thread;
    std::atomic<bool> _threadRunning;
}
```

It might be important to note that, depending on the code in your loop, it might take a while before the thread really stops.
Therefore it might be wise to `std::thread::join` the thread before restarting it, to make sure only one thread runs at a time.

Comment: Why not `while(_threadRunning)` instead of `for(int i = 0; i < 999999; i++)`? It is more readable. Also it may be necessary to use `std::atomic_bool` instead of `bool`.

Comment: @JorgeBellon - This was the OPs example code. I just expanded on it to demonstrate how it could be interrupted.
I am assuming it is just a placeholder for a loop with a high, but still a finite, number of iterations.

Comment: @JorgeBellon - In which scenario would `bool` not be atomic on the mentioned architectures? But it is a good point to keep the example portable and therefore make `_threadRunning` an `std::atomic<bool>`

Comment: @Detonar is correct. The loop shall be executed a finite number of times, specified by the application user. If the requirements change and there is a need for infinite iteration, I would implement a while loop instead. The above example works, but: do I need to take care to join the thread again?

Comment: Not using `std::atomic<bool>` might not break anything in a simple example, but it's a bad general advice. There's more things to consider then if the read/write is atomic.

Comment: @szumial - If you need th start the thread right again, you should join it, yes. Take into consideration that joining might freeze your GUI again. If you join, i would advice doing so in `MyClass::start`, before a new thread has to be started. This way you only wait in your `std::thread::join` if you really have to.

Comment: Expanded the example to join the thread now the way i would do it.

Comment: @Detonar accepted your answer. The only thing I changed is the start() method, which I prefer to be of a void type and handle the thread detach and join itself, without exposing the thread object to an external entity. Thank you for the good example.